# double sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Simple question, rather linguistic one.

Having two sequence
\begin{align*}
R_1&=\{a,b,c,d,e,\ldots\}\\
R_2&=\{a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d,e,e,\ldots\}
\end{align*}
I want to say (mathematically corect):  $R_2$ is *doubled(?)* sequence of $R_1$.

Any better, more informative, ideas?
Of course I will also give this sequences in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the first sequence $(a_n)_n$. If I were you, I would introduce the "doubled sequence" of $(a_n)_n$ as the sequence $(b_n)_n$ defined by
$$
b_{2n} = b_{2n-1} := a_n.
$$
After you've defined what it means to be a "doubled sequence" then there's no harm in using the term even if it's not a commonly used term.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this not to be a common definition, so it probably has no agreed upon name. This means you can pick any name you want, as long as you define it explicitly. Do try to come up with a good descriptive name though. Naming it the doubled sequence seems a bit too ambiguous to me. Maybe call it the element repetitor? Or the double copy?